# Trying to load selected (by query ) Data from a Database

Tags: android, crash

Trying to load a big table from a Database and I am getting this exception:

```
03-22 09:39:52.898: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException:     Address family not supported by protocol
03-22 09:39:57.228: ERROR/CursorWindow(3890): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 36, freeSpace() = 9, numRows = 20315
03-22 09:39:57.228: ERROR/CursorWindow(3890): not growing since there are already 20315 row(s), max size 1048576
03-22 09:39:57.228: ERROR/CursorWindow(3890): The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot 20314
03-22 09:39:57.228: ERROR/Cursor(3890): Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0 row 20314
```

I understand that there is no enough space in the emulator that is correct?

what should i do to fix that?

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Load less data.

Seriously - real devices are limited on memory too. So even if you increase the memory settings for the emulator, you will run into issues with real devices.

Usually you only need to load as much data as fits on screen and can then load more when the user is scrolling around.